# Is it bad that CLion adds header files to cmake source files?

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

When I create a new pair of .h and .cpp file with clion using the following dialog

[image]

if I check "add to targets" and "create an associated header", it modifies the line `set(SOURCE_FILES ...)` which it later passes to `add_executable` so that it containes both `new_source_file.h` and `new_source_file.cpp`. If I understand C++ and cmake correctly, it is bad, because header files should not be compiled by themselves. Am I right? Is this a problem with CLion?

Comment: interesting; I use CMake myself and never add .h files in the SOURCE_FILES...

Answer (score 4):

It's correct to add headers to CMakeLists.txt.

CMake is smart enough and doesn't invoke the compiler on headers, but adding them to the CMakeLists.txt makes sure that they are referenced in the projects generated by cmake (for example, Visual Studio projects and Code Block projects). This in turn makes it possible to show the headers (and not only the .cpp files) in the "project" pane of most IDEs which support cmake.

If you don't add them, the compilation itself should work fine, but the IDE probably won't know that such headers are part of your project, thus they won't be included in the project pane, in the "search in project" function and so on.

Comment: In the case of macOS/iPhoneOS framework generation you must add the PUBLIC_HEADERS to add_library or the framework will not correctly get the headers copied in. I've seen a blog post on the Internet that this is an anti-pattern, but they're wrong.

Answer (score 2):

From [CLion's FAQ](http://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2014/09/clion-answers-frequently-asked-questions/):

> using **set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)** is how CLion now knows that main.cpp is included in your project.
>   As for now, header files (in case their names differ from the
>   appropriate .cpp files already added to the SOURCE_FILES variable)
>   should also be included in the project in that way.

In your case, you don't need to specify `lcm.h` when setting `SOURCE_FILES`, but it also doesn't hurt.